# Passing arguments to $webclient.DownloadFile() in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using PowerShell for the first time for a small task. I have a text file on disk with file download url links.Text file has several links line by line. I want to download to disk. I tried using the following code.

```
$filepath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\filelinks.txt"
$files = Get-Content $filepath
$i=0

foreach($fileurl in $files){
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$file = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"+$i+".csv"
$webclient.DownloadFile($fileurl,$file)
$i++
}
```

But I get the following error

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."
At line:8 char:1
+ $webclient.DownloadFile($fileurl,$file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

The links in text file

```
"http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/I1.csv"
"http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/E1.csv"
"http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/E2.csv"
"http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/SP1.csv"
"http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/D1.csv"
```

How should i pass the right arguments here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the URLs *in your file* are enclosed in `"..."` - actual double quotes that, when read with `Get-Content`, become a *literal* part of the lines read - which is not the intent (*embedded* `"` chars. are not allowed in URLs, which explains the error you saw).

- Either: Update file `C:\Users\User\Desktop\filelinks.txt` by removing the enclosing `"` instances from each line.
- Or: Remove the enclosing `"` instances after having read the lines with `Get-Content`:

  - `$fileurl = $fileurl -replace '^"(.*)"$', '$1'`